# Can I call a method through an array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, call

For example, I want to create an array that have pointers to call a method. 
This is what I'm trying to say:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlankSlate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number.");
        int k = kb.nextInt();

         Array[] = //Each section will call a method };
         Array[1] = number();

         if (k==1){
             Array[1]; //calls the method
         }
    }

    private static void number(){
        System.out.println("You have called this method through an array");
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if I'm not being descriptive enough or if my formatting is wrong. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Create an array (or list) of an interface like Runnable and do `array[i].run()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @ikh answered, your `array` should be a `Runnable[]`.

[`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is an interface that defines a `run()` method.

You can then initialize your array and latter call a method as follows:

```
Runnable[] array = new Runnable[ARRAY_SIZE];

// as "array[1] = number();" in your "pseudo" code
// initialize array item
array[1] = new Runnable() { public void run() { number(); } };

// as "array[1];" in your "pseudo" code
// run the method
array[1].run();
```

Since Java 8, you can use a lamda expression to write a simpler functional interface implementation. So your array can be initialized with:

```
// initialize array item
array[1] = () -> number();
```

You'll then still use `array[1].run();` to run the method.

Comment: I changed the variable name from `Array` to `array` because the Java convention recommends variable names should start with lowecase letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can make array of `Runnable`. In java, `Runnable` is used instead of function pointer[C] or delegates[C#] (as far as I know)

```
Runnable[] arr = new Runnable[] {
    new Runnable() { public void run() { number(); } }
};
arr[0].run();
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/gPks0K)

Comment: To improve this answer, consider demonstrating lambda syntax.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Oh thanks. I'm still a freshman on recent java >o<

Comment: I'm very new to Java, but do initialize the Runnable array like any other array?

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively create a method array and invoke each method, which would perhaps be closer to what you requested in your question. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        // find the method
        Method number = TestMethodCall.class.getMethod("number", (Class<?>[])null);

        // initialize the array, presumably with more than one entry
        Method [] methods = {number};

        // call method through array
        for (Method m: methods) {
            // parameter is null since method is static
            m.invoke(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}


public static void number(){
    System.out.println("You have called this method through an array");
}
```

The only caveat is that *number()* had to be made public so it could be found by *getMethod()*.